# more precise numeric datatype than double?

Tags: java, types

Is there a datatype in Java that stores a decimal number more precisely than a `double`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, use [java.math.BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class. It can represent numbers with great precision.

If you just need huge integers, you can use [java.math.BigInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead.

They both extend [java.math.Number](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html).

You can even use your existing doubles if you need:

```
double d = 67.67;
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d);
```

And you can get BigDecimal values out of databases with JDBC:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()) {
    BigDecimal bd = rs.getBigDecimal("column_with_number");
}
```

Unfortunately, since Java does not support operator overloading, you can't use regular symbols for common mathematical operations like you would in C# and the `decimal` type.

You will need to write code like this:

```
BigDecimal d1 = new BigDecimal(67.67);
BigDecimal d2 = new BigDecimal(67.68);
BidDecimal d3 = d1.add(d2); // d1 + d2 is invalid
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes: the java.math.BigDecimal class.

Answer (score 2):

Use BigDecimal it offers much better precision

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use an arbitrary precision class such as [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 2):

you can use a [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

To calculate with with BigDeciamls this class provides special methods that are used instead of the standard operators e.g. `+ - * / ...` that you from int, double and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the range of your input. Many times, you can just use int or long. For money, just store the integer number of pennies. int will handle up to $20,000,000.00 which is large enough for my bank account. long goes far higher.

If your range is suitable, using long is much faster and cleaner than using BigDecimal